# How to export Kotlin Extensions into aar?

Tags: android, maven, aar, kotlin-android-extensions

I created some extensions that I want to export into an aar library, then I deployed them to my local maven. When I try to use them in another project they are not found.

Inspecting the .m2 directory (jar) I can see the kt files with the extensions, however inspecting the generated aar I see no reference to those files:

- `BitmapResolver` is an object class that is imported.
- `TextViewCompat` and `TextInputCompat` have extensions.

[image: Comparison Inspector vs file]

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I was just missing to do a "`make`" before running "`publishToMavenLocal`"

Now it works.